# Mis Datos de formulario PHP no se envian a la base de datos MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

```html
<?php

$conectar = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','root','official');

if(!$conectar){

echo "no se conecto";

}

?>


 <form method="post" action="cargar.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">

   <h1>Titulo para tu archivo:<h1><input  name="titulo" required type="text" placeholder="Ponle un titulo" class="uno">

   <h1>Seleciona tu archivo:</h1><input name="archivo" type="file" required  class="file">

   <h1>Agregar una descripcion:</h1><input name="descripcion" required type="text" maxlength="45"   class="descripcion" placeHolder="Maximo de 45 caracteres...">

   <h1>Sistema Operativo:<h1><select name="so"  required class="select"  required>

<option>Windows 7</option>
<option>Windows 8</option>
<option>Windows 8.1</option>
<option>Windows 10</option>
<option>MacOs</option>
<option>Ios</option>
<option>Android</option>
<option>Linux</option>

</select>  



   <center><input type="submit" name="subir" value="Archivo Listo" class="botom"></center>


</form>


<?php

if(isset($_POST('subir'))){

$titulo = $_POST['titulo']; 
$archivo = $_POST['archivo'];
$descripcion =  $_POST['descripcion'];
$tipo   = $_POST['archivo']['type'];
$fecha =    $_POST['d/m/y'];
$sistemaoperativo = $_POST['so'];   
$correo = $_POST[''];
$tamaño = $_POST['archivo']['size'];
$descargas = $_POST[''];    
$confiable = $_POST[''];

$insertar = "INSERT INTO archivos (titulo,archivo,descripcion,tipo,fecha,sistemaoperativo,correo,tamaño,descargas,confiable) 
VALUES ('$titulo','$archivo','$descripcion','$tipo','$fecha','$sistemaoperativo','$correo','$tamaño','$descargas','$confiable')"

$subir = mysqli_query($conectar, $insertar);

if(!$subir){

echo "no se cargo";

}else{

   echo "si se cargo";

}



}

?>
```

Cuando Subo un registro con un archivo a mi base de datos no se envia o me sale error al subirlo. Yo Pongo el codigo 100% correcto como va en los tutoriales y me sale error o no carga... Porfavor.[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]T_T

Esta es la conexion a la Base de datos...
Me funciona excelente.

[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][2]][2]

Aca esta el formulario con los datos, con los name;

Y aca esta el codigo para publicar los datos a la Base de datos.

**Deje algunos corchetes en blanco. Para completarlos despues. **

Comment: Hola: No se ve bien el código. Intenta ponerlo completo. ¿Dónde haces el submit del formulario?. Saludos

Comment: necesito que pegues el código y elimines las imágenes, no pienso re-escribir todo eso que agregaste...

Answer (score 0):

No uses $_REQUEST usa $_POST, mira esta respuesta para que te des una idea de la diferencia entre estos.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1924958

Ahora, primero revisa que si se este entrando al primer **if**, que es donde esta asignando los datos del formulario.

Hazle un var_dump al **$_POST['titulo']** o en si a la variable $titulo, para así poder verificar que si estas leyendo los campos del fomulario, si esta todo bien pues ya te toca hacer el **INSERT**.

Y por ultimo, se va a mostrar el mensaje de "*Se debe hacer POST*", si estas entrando de forma directa al archivo **cargar.php**, para eso usar el **heder('Location')**, para **redirigir** al **publicar.php** (*solo descomenta la linea para que primero veas el mensaje*)

subir.php

```
if( isset( $_POST['SUBIR'] ) ){

    echo "Leyendo datos del formulario";

    //Asignamos valores
    $titulo = $_POST['titulo'];
    var_dump( $titulo );
    var_dump( $_POST['titulo'] );


    //Hacemos el insert
    INSERT INTO .... bla bla bla...

    if( $subir ) {
        echo "Si se subio con exito";
    } else {
        echo "Error al subir";
    }

} else {

    echo "Se debe de hacer POST";
    //header('Location: publicar.php');

}
```

Comment: Amigoo no me funciono. :(  la realidad es que antes me funcionaban con otros codigo sin ningun problema, pero ahora no funciona, nose si es por alguna actualizacion o por que ocupaba mucho la base de datos pero no funciona. Y otra cosa y si quiero poner el codigo de cargar.php en el publicar.php?. Osea si que tenga que ir a otra pagina y volver...?

Comment: Que es lo que no funciono, esta entrando a la parte del if( isset( $_POST['SUBIR'] )  ? y si es asi esta leyendo los valores del form ?

Comment: no lo se amigo, no creo que sea un error de codigo, por que yo antes ponia el codigo como en los tutoriales y me funcionaba, ahora no me funciona con el mismo codigo. Tienes Alguna Idea de eso?? :( saludos

Comment: que usas para levantar el localhost ?, xampp, wamp, lamp ?, busca el archivo php_error_log en aqui:  php\logs\php_error_log o si no en: logs/php_error_log, y y busca el final del archivo que error te esta registrando

Comment: uso MAMP... antes usaba Xampp pero me dejo de funcionar.

Comment: como identifico el error amigo :v soy principiante.

Comment: por favor amiguito...

Comment: No he usado MAMP, solo XAMPP y WAMP, busca como encontrar los logs de los errores de MAMP, cuando lo encuentres, trata de guardar de nuevo usando tu formulario, revisa de nuevo el archivo de los logs y busca el ultimo error y pon en tu pregunta lo que te dice el error.

Comment: ok amigo, lo intentare GRACIAS

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que vas a subir es un archivo, se usa $_FILES para procesar el archivo y $_POST para los otros campos del formulario. De manera simple es así (recuerda que tu input se llama 'archivo'):

```
// Primero creas un directorio para almacenar el archivo
$folder = '/archivos';

$origen = $_FILES["archivo"]["tmp_name"];
$destino = $folder . $_FILES["archivo"]["name"];

if (copy($origen, $destino)) {
    // Aqui ejecutas la inserción de los otros campos en la BD
    // ya que no hubo problemas al subir el archivo
    $sql = "INSERT INTO archivos SET archivo = 'destino' "; // ... etc.
} else {
    // Ocurrió algún error, lo manejas aqui
}
```

Puedes agregar chequeos por tipo de archivo (tal vez solo necesitas imágenes), tamaño, etc. Hay un ejemplo aqui: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

Comment: no bro, ese no es mi problema es que el titulo,descripcion,archivos,etc... no me se me envia a la base de datos.

Comment: Según el formulario, el procesamiento se hace en el archivo cargar.php. ¿Es así como lo tienes (dos archivos, uno con el formulario y otro que se llama cargar.php con el código para subir a la BD)?

Comment: sip. pero  tambien pruebo con escribir en el archivo de formulario.

Comment: escribes isset($_POST('subir')), lo correcto es isset($_POST['subir'])   ¿Notas el cambio de los paréntesis?